# Spring WebClient equivalent of Http request.setEntity()?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm currently trying to refactor older HTTP code to work with Spring boot WebClient.

I have this older code for a POST method :

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);

request.addHeader(AUTHORIZATION, token);

request.addHeader("Accept", "*/*");

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>();

nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", grantType));

nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("scope", DEFAULT));

request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

I was wondering if there was a way to do something similar to setEntity in WebClient? Here is what I have so far..

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> bodyValues = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();

bodyValues.add("grant_type", grantType);

bodyValues.add("scope", DEFAULT);

WebClient webClient = WebClient.create();

String resp = webClient.post().uri(new URI(url))

            .header(AUTHORIZATION, token)

            .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

            .header("Accept", "*/*")

            .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData(bodyValues))

            .retrieve()

            .bodyToMono(String.class)

            .block();
```

But adding the multivaluemap to the body doesn't work. If anyone knows anything about this, help would be much appreciated! Thank you

Comment: What does it mean "adding the multivaluemap to the body doesn't work"? Do you get an exception? No exception but nothing is in the request body?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

```java
String resp = webClient.post().uri(new URI(url))
            .header(AUTHORIZATION, token)
            .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
            .header("Accept", "*/*")
            .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData("grant_type", grantType).with("scope", DEFAULT))
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class)
            .block();
```